# Relaxation oscillator period

Tags: theory

For an electronics project I am using a Schmitt Trigger relaxation oscillator. The equation for voltage across a capacitor in time *t* is

$$V_c = V_s(1-e^{\frac{-t}{RC}})$$

My Schmitt Trigger uses a 1mF capacitor and a 5k resistor. The threshold voltages of the chip I am using are 0.9 and 3.6V. Rearranging the equation for t gives

$$t = -RCln(\frac{V_c}{V_s})$$

Inserting values into the equation to see how long it takes to charge the capacitor from 0.9V to 3.6V gives *t* to be approximately 7 seconds. In experiment however the entire period of the oscillator is only about 2.5 seconds. What have I got wrong in the theory?

Diagram:

[image]

Comment: What is that ST gate? Most ST gates have a hysteresis that is much less than 2.7V (3.6V - 0.9V) on a 5V supply. For example, the HC14 has a typical 900mV deadband on a 4.5V supply. That will result in a much higher frequency of oscillation (which is exactly what you are seeing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first equation you have models a capacitor charging from 0 to Vs. What you need to do is figure out what values of t correspond to the thresholds, and subtract those to get the time it takes to charge from one threshold to the other.

Also, you made a small mistake in your algebra.

$$V_c = V_s\left(1-e^{\frac{-t}{RC}}\right)$$

$$\frac{V_c}{V_s} = 1-e^{\frac{-t}{RC}}$$

$$e^{\frac{-t}{RC}} = 1 - \frac{V_c}{V_s}$$

$$\frac{-t}{RC} = \ln\left(1 - \frac{V_c}{V_s}\right)$$

$$t = -R C \ln\left(1 - \frac{V_c}{V_s}\right)$$

Then you want to use

$$t_{rise} = -R C \left[ \ln\left(1 - \frac{V_{c,final}}{V_s}\right) - \ln\left(1 - \frac{V_{c,initial}}{V_s}\right) \right]$$

to get the risetime.

For Vs = 5, initial voltage of 0.7 (from the diode) and final voltage of 3.0 (Vt+ from the datasheet), you get trise = 3.82.  I presume the actual Vt+ may be a bit less than 3 volts.  A final voltage of 2.4 volts gives a risetime of 2.5 seconds.

Comment: My source voltage is 5V

Comment: Using your answer, I get this sum: $(-5000*{10^-3}*ln(\frac{3.6}{5}))-(-5000*{10^-3}*ln(\frac{0.9}{5}))$, which still equates to about 7.

Comment: Can you post a schematic and list specifically what parts you are using?

Comment: I'm just dealing with the theory at the moment, so assume I am using ideal components. Even if they had an effect it does not explain the time difference

Comment: There may be a faulty assumption somewhere that needs to be rooted out. If you have measurements from something you actually built, then post a schematic so we can figure out what the discrepancy is.

Comment: OK, I'll post a circuit diagram in my question

Comment: Ignore the potentiometer for the moment, just pretend only 5k is on the feedback loop

Comment: What is the full part number for your inverter?

Comment: CMOS 40106 Hex Schmitt Inverter

Comment: Data sheet here: http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/HEF40106B.pdf

Comment: Cap will be discharged to one diode drop above ground (around 0.7v) and then will charge up to Vt+, which is around 3.0 volts.  -5000*10^-3*(ln(1-3/5)-ln(1-0.7/5)) = 3.82, which is much closer.  I also just realized that you made a mistake with the algebra, that should be ln(1-Vc/Vs) .

Comment: yes, that's much closer. Another quick question: the formula we are supposed to use for calculating the time period is T= 0.5RC. Why does this one work?

Comment: T = 0.5RC is the time it takes to charge to about 40% capacity (1-e^-0.5), which is around where the logic threshold will be.  T = RC is time time it takes to get to 63% capacity (1-1/e).

Comment: Wow...that's enlightening xD. Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

The equations of alex.forencich should also look at the discharge half period (since 0.9V and 3.6V are not evenly spaced from 0V and 5V):

$$
V(t)=V_H\exp(-t/RC) \\
t=-RC\ln (V(t)/V_H)
$$

Then find the fall time \$t_{f}\$ to \$V_L\$ by setting \$V(t)=V_L=0.9\,\textrm{Volt}\$

$$
t_f=-RC\ln (V_L/V_H)\\
=-5\,\textrm{k}\Omega\cdot 1\,\textrm{mF} \cdot \ln (0.9/3.6) = 3.01\,\textrm{s}\\
$$

So the fall "half" period should be 3.01 seconds.

It is possible to "flip" the voltage references for this equation to find the rise time \$t_{r}\$:

$$
t_r=-RC\ln ((V_S-V_H)/(V_S-V_L)) = 2.33\,\textrm{s}
$$

So the full period would be \$t_r+t_f\$, which is about 5.34 seconds.

In practice the following can *shorten* the period:

- Noise voltage on the Schmitt Trigger input.
- Real capacitors and resistances.
- Varition in threshold voltages of Schmitt Trigger.

From experience, most likely you have a much smaller C than you expect, although other explanations are certainly possible and a smaller R is the next candidate to investigate.

Comment: True.  I was analyzing it as a one shot due to the button, though.

Comment: Yeah, that's ok. But if the button is not pushed it oscillates :).

Comment: Using the threshold numbers from the datasheet, rise is 1.68 and fall is 1.55 for a total period of 3.23.